# Threads on bare-metal embedded devices

Tags: multithreading, arm, pthreads, bare-metal

Are threads(or pthreads) supported on bare-metal arm devices. I am using ARM/GNU C++(arm-none-eabi-g++)compiler and I am getting the error "cannot find -lpthread"  upon compilation though I have given the flag -lpthread in linker command.

Comment: Which device are you using? Are you really using is bare-metal? Or do you have a minimalistic OS? For what do you plan the threads?

Comment: I am using Microchip's SAML11

Comment: SAML11 comes with crytographic accelerators. I want to run one thread on the cryptographic accelerator and another thread on the main processor.

Comment: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html

Comment: the datasheet implies that this is simply some code that they have put in rom for you, which implies you can take any mcu and a library and just use that which you can easily slice up in a superloop.  If they had hardware acceleration I would expect they would have worded things differently, granted I didnt read every page...

Comment: _Nothing_ is "supported" on bare metal devices. That's what "bare metal" means. It's only truly bare metal if every instruction that the application executes was compiled from source code in your project's repo. No dependencies.

Comment: @Solomon: I think I know what you mean, but even "bare metal" devices usually come with support from the vendor in the form of support libraries, middleware and hardware abstraction layers. See CMSIS for ARM. Or so one would hope. :-)

Comment: yeah, this whole bare metal thing gets a bit fuzzy as does that include all these libraries that in many cases you are not directly talking to hardware but to libraries/apis.  there are numerous definitions (and spellings, baremetal, bare metal, bare-metal, and some places place special meaning for each spelling, others dont).   No real answer as to what bare metal means.  without an OS though is often agreed upon.

Comment: vendors that want to stay in business need to offer an ide with an sdk, toolchain, debugger, etc...and so they do in some form.  also to keep it fresh and such they tend to change that environment every so many years, for look and feel if nothing else.

Comment: maybe the confusion is the assumption that mcus are all bare metal which they are not bare metal programming is a software thing not hardware, you can write bare metal code for your pc all day long we get questions on that regularly...If that is the case then "just" use one of the many operating system options (freertos, atomthreads, etc).  but that in no way means the threads option on the toolchain will work.

Answer (score 6):

Without an operating system which supports preemptive multitasking you do not have threads. This is what the term "bare metal" refers to.

Neither g++ nor the linker can give you thread functionality. Only an operating system can provide threads.

You can of course build your own thread handling in your own bare-metal application, but this is a substantial task.

Interrupt routines usually preempt the main program on bare-metal devices and can be thought of as periodically triggered threads. And a periodic timer interrupt can be used to switch thread contexts. This is the first step towards a preemptive multitasking operating system.

Comment: Can you please explain by what do you mean by "build your own thread handling in your own bare-metal application". Is there any other way other than threads that I can use to make crytographic accelerator and the main processor  work simultaneously.

Comment: Even on bare-metal you can have stuff run in parallel or pseudo parallel, for example all the interrupt routines run pseudo-parallel. And of course you can offload work to other hardware like your cryptographic coprocessor. Just start the crypto work, do something else on the main processor meanwhile, and synchronize later. And you can do cooperative multitasking (aka fibers or coroutines) if you can see any use for that.

Comment: @Mehreen You can achieve preemptive multi-tasking on your platform by using [FreeRTOS](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/atmel-42382-getting-started-with-freertos-on-atmel-sam-flash-mcus_applicationnote_at04056.pdf)  for example: you will be able to start multiple tasks from your main program the same way you would have started multiple threads on a general purpose operating system such as Linux or Windows, but using a different API.

Comment: It is not that difficult of a task to have these two things happening, you do have to task switch if you want but that can be as simple as your non-crypto code runs in a periodic interrupt and you limit its execution time to leave a percentage for the crypto task.  Or you simply wait for the crypto to finish...  You can also check prices and use smaller parts and have two parts one just for crypto and one for everything else.

Comment: @old_timer Yes, this would not be 'baremetal anymore,  I do agree 100%. This is just that given how the question was formulated, I thought the person asking it may have a different conception of 'baremetal' than you and me.

Comment: @old_timer: Yes, FreeRTOS is not bare metal anymore. Exactly. A good pointer through, since FreeRTOS is one answer to the question "how do I get threads on my bare-metal": Use a minimalistic OS, like an RTOS.

Comment: "switch thread contexts" this is considering just a single core? What multi-core bare-metal embedded device, which has more cores than threads in the application (each thread will be able to run on its own core).

Comment: @AntonKrug: Yes, this is just considering a single core. If you have a CPU with multiple cores and/or with hyperthreading you have multiple threads even on bare metal. And then you will have all the problems of multithreaded programming, even on bare metal. It is, however, quite some work to write a bare-metal application which uses multiple cores. You need to properly start up the tother cores, define the cache coherency you want, set up separate stacks. And you need to have some code for the thread synchronization primitives. Pthreads won't do, as this relies on an OS.

Comment: @Johannes Overmann getting stacks setup and executing them is easy, and even multithreaded application is easy, if there is not much intercommunication (when each thread just does something independently from the other), the trick is to get them working but get them working in 'pthreads' style. While most online content still assumes that baremetal must be just single core and it's about scheduling multiple tasks on the same thread.

Comment: @AntonKrug: Yes, exactly. pthreads is about abstracting the multithreading capabilities of the hardware away (e.g. allowing the application to create and destroy threads), while running a bare-metal multithreaded on the hardware is quite different. You just have the threads. Getting pthreads to run on bare-metal, implementing a multithreading system, is half-way to a simple OS.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need really pthreads (just you were not aware of other techniques), then coroutines might be a solution for you.

`A coroutine is a function that can suspend execution to be resumed later. Coroutines are stackless: they suspend execution by returning to the caller and the data that is required to resume execution is stored separately from the stack. This allows for sequential code that executes asynchronously (e.g. to handle non-blocking I/O without explicit callbacks), and also supports algorithms on lazy-computed infinite sequences and other uses.`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines

In simple terms it's something between functions and threads. You do not have to wait for them to finish executing like regular functions, and do not have to be part of an OS (FreeRTOS is an OS) to have a thread (pthread or other) feature.

This is a new C++20 feature that you could have supported on your embedded toolchain. However, there is a nice blog post on implementing them in a C language.

http://www.vishalchovatiya.com/coroutine-in-c-language/

I'm not including the content from the blog as it's not a small snippet, but I made a redundant snapshot just in case the original website will go down:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210428125420/http://www.vishalchovatiya.com/coroutine-in-c-language/

Comment: Good suggestion for bare-metal (and even all other) use cases. Coroutines is essentially cooperative multitasking. You can have them with stack and stackless. I am not sure the pointer to the C++20 coroutines is helpful though. I recently looked at the spec and it seems to be horrendously complex. But some low-level RTOSes support coroutines, and sometimes call them "tasks", so  a good point when talking about bare-metal. +1

Comment: Thanks, was thinking about longjump setjump for while, how that could be used with a small embedded focused scheduler, to bring something to bare-metal without having an OS, but then where is the line between having fancy bare-metal application and having a very simplified OS.